# How to convert this forumal to a proper code?

Tags: machine-learning, r, algorithms

I have the following formula [1] that I attempted to transform in to a function via R. However, my initial outputs are disconcerting. Before I go through many blocks (images), I am hoping to get assistance with QC. The formula & my attempt to transform it are below:

> Where $f_k(i,j)$ is the intensity value of pixel$(i,j)$ in block $k$ & $\mu_k$ is the mean value of all pixels in $k$.

$$\sigma_k = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^H \sum_{j=1}^H(f_k(i,j)-\mu_k)^2} {H*H}}
$$

```r
library(raster)
image_files<- list.files(".",pattern = "*.PNG$")
img_A<-raster(image_files[1])
matrix_A<-raster::as.matrix(img_A)
>>dim(matrix_A) 
174,288
sigma_k<-sd(matrix_A)
```

> Where $c_k$ is the center pixel intensity in $k$ and $t=2.97$

$$ L_k = \frac{1 | f_k(i,j)-c_k|<t \sigma_k} {0  |f_k(i,j)-c_k|>t \sigma_k}
$$

```r
center_A<-matrix_A[144,144]
t<-2.97

k<-apply(matrix_A,2,function(x) {x-center_A})
sigma_t<-sigma_k*t

Lk<-lapply(k, function(x) {
if (x < sigma_t){
x=1} else {
x=0
}
})

Lk<-unlist(Lk)

block_label<-data.frame(sort(table(Lk),decreasing=T)
```

> Finally, a comparison is conducted to identify majority "0" *or* "1". The majority is assigned as the mean intensity value of all pixels in the present block.

$\bar I_{\mathbf i \mathbf n} = [\hat I_{\mathbf i \mathbf n,1}, \hat I_{\mathbf i \mathbf n,2}, \hat I_{\mathbf i \mathbf n,3},...\hat I_{\mathbf i \mathbf n, n}]$

[1]https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2017/4728425/